# Why don't the Valar do anything about the One Ring?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-silmarillion, the-one-ring

After reading the Silmarillion, I wondered why the Valar, being near-gods, don't do anything about Sauron. They certainly possess the power; without Morgoth, Sauron is just in his shadow. At least Eru should be able to do something. Sorry if this has been asked before, I'm just a bit curious.

Comment: It's certainly similar, and I *think* it answers the question. If it doesn't, edit your question to clarify what you're asking.

Comment: @SSumner - yup, at least two answers on the other question deal with this directly (referencing the obvious Council of Elrond quote), and others also give good reasoning.  I'm going to close as dupe and see if the OP and the community thinks otherwise.

Comment: By the way, and taking inspiration from @suchiuomizu's answer, "why did the Valar send the Istari rather than intervening directly?" would be a good variant on this question that I don't think has been asked or answered before (the answer is in the Istari essay in Unfinished Tales, but if you don't have that book or would like to have the answer on this site it would seem worth asking).

Comment: Yes, I agree they're similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They sent the Istari.  That was the whole point of their arrival.  And based of Gandalf's implications Eru was involved and was the only reason the Ring was successfully destroyed in the first place (I'll dig up the quote shortly).

Found the quote regarding Eru's implied involvement.

> "Behind that there was something else at work, beyond any design of
>   the Ring-maker. I can put it no plainer than by saying that Bilbo was
>   meant to find the Ring, and not by its maker. In which case you also
>   were meant to have it. And that may be an encouraging thought."

Comment: Now that's a good answer: "they did". :)

Comment: Oh of course...forgot about that. It seems obvious now that I know

Comment: That, and their boss had His own input as well; not only in steering it towards Frodo, but making sure that Frodo's lapse at the end was not catastrophic.